# Oracle - Expressões regulares

Tags: regex, oracle11g

Caros,
Preciso descobrir quais usuários possuem o padrão de login "E012345", ou seja, incia-se com a letra E e procede com uma cadeia de números.

Eu tentei a query abaixo nas não rolou:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_usuarios
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE  (usr_login, 'E%^n$');
```

Alguém me ajuda por favor?

Comment: Não ficou muito claro mas talvez: `'^E[:digit:]{6}$'`, letra 'E' seguida de 6 algarismos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a expressão `[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1,}` para qualquer letra seguida de uma sequência de números com 1 ou mais algarismos. 


Você pode usar a expressão `[Ee][0-9]{1,}` para qualquer ocorrência que se inicie com a letra "E" ou "e" seguida de uma sequência de números com 1 ou mais algarismos.


Se o sistema estiver configurado para CASE INSENSITIVE você pode ignorar as letras maiúsculas na expressão.

Comment: Só um detalhe, `{1}` é redundante e pode ser removido - `[A-Za-z]{1}` é o mesmo que `[A-Za-z]` (na verdade, de maneira geral, `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`. E `{1,}` é equivalente a `+`, então poderia ser `[Ee][0-9]+` - ou ainda `[Ee]\d+`

Comment: Perfeito. Você está certo. É que eu dou prioridade á escrita explícita. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Luciano B. M.
Obrigado, deu certo!

A query completa ficou assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_usuarios
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE    (usr_login, '[Ee][0-9]{1,}')
```

Comment: Vc também pode usar `[Ee][0-9]+` pois o `+` é equivalente a `{1,}`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm#r3c1-t7 - e também poderia ser `[Ee]\d+` (o `\d` é um atalho equivalente a `[0-9]`)